# 9patch images stretching incorrectly

Tags: android, xml, button, nine-patch

[image]

(*The black lines are not visible so I just made a replica of it in photoshop and enhanced the black lines for you people to understand.* )

[image: The black lines are photoshopped. JUST so they look a bit visible here. This is only an amplified line to make it easier for people to understand. **Note, I have NOT used PS]

( *The black lines are photoshopped. JUST so they look a bit visible here.* )

Suppose, this is the 9patch image, i have broadened the 9patch black line in photoshop so its clearly visible.

This is how it is going to stretch. The logo remain in its original dimensions, only the blue space will stretch. 
In the 9patch software, the X and Y coordinate results were perfect and they stretch the way they should.

However, when I insert this in my xml code, **I get this result.**

[image]

**WHY is the logo part stretching ?** 
WHATEVER the dimensions of the layout may be, the logo should be in its right size , while the space around it SHOULD adjust , but its not happening so.

Edit::
The images in the jar preview fine, but when I actually use that resource in some layout, I get the incorrectly rendered result.

***The xml code for the button :***

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_normal" />
```

Comment: Simply said, your 9 patch is **poorly designed**

Comment: where did you place 9patch (full file name)?

Comment: the borders have to be TRANSPARENT and have to be 1px wide/tall and only have PURE BLACK 1px markings

Comment: okay, the borders are artificially done for the sake of presentation,
they're originally on the transparent space and made using draw9patch, so they are also 1 pixel wide/tall.

Comment: @DerGolem can you elaborate how?

Comment: Please, put the actual 9 patch here. NOT a PhotoShop ELABORATION, which is MEANINGLESS, to us.

Comment: It seems that you **SCALED** your image (no real black on transparent border found) + there's a huge transparent border... are you sure it's the correct image?

Comment: now I have uploaded a bigger version of the SAME image. I guess you can see the black lines now.

Comment: Now I have uploaded the **correct** version of your logo. And it **works**. Make sure you put it in the `/res/drawable` folder and it ends in **.9.png**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my version: **logo.9.png**

[image]

As you can see, it works just perfectly

[image]

Make sure you put it in the `/res/drawable` folder and it ends in **.9.png**

Comment: Okay, the stretching looked perfect when I had done too. 
I think the problem was with the size of the buttons. 
When I decreased the size, it was stretching perfectly on a normal sized display. But large buttons were acting in an incorrect manner.

Answer (score 2):

You do it wrong, To make a `9patch` using `photoshop`:
1- add a new transparent `1-pixel` in each image side (left, right, top and bottom)
2- draw the `scaling` and `content` in that transparent pixel (black color #000000), not over the image content it self.
3- save it as `your_image_name.9.png`

Comment: I dont make the 9patch image in photoshop, I make it using the software provided by eclipse. draw9patch tool. 
the lines were not clearly visible so I just enhanced them with photoshop, originally its on the transparent space.

Comment: then regenerate the image using 'draw9patch', and don't play with it using another tool. 'draw9patch' tool know the best. btw it comes with android-sdk not eclipse.

Comment: I DID NOT play with the original. 
See the edit. 
The original 9 patch image created with draw9patch
The other one is just for people to understand the black lines. Not used in code.

Comment: while you keep playing with images no one can help you. please post the original image, the 9-patch image and the result WITHOUT modification.

Comment: I have. Please see the first and the last image . Original images. And tell me , why is the stretching incorrect?